# Loop doesn't iterate through listview

Tags: c#, listview

Could someone help me with this problem I am having? I am trying to search through a listview for occurrences of a string inputted via a textbox and record the location index value. Now although the code could be improved... it works. The problem I am having is the loop doesn't iterate. The code only displays the first index value even if there are more than one occurrences.
Could someone show me how to get this loop to loop?

Thanks in advance...

```
 foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items){
    foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subItem in item.SubItems){
        if (subItem.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToLower())){
            var index = listView1.FindItemWithText(textBox1.Text.ToLower()); 
            MessageBox.Show(listView1.Items.IndexOf(index).ToString());
            count++;
        }                
    }   
 }
```

Comment: From the docs for  [`FindItemWithText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.finditemwithtext(v=vs.110).aspx): _Finds the **first** ListViewItem with that begins with the given text value._ You want the version that takes a start index: [`ListView.FindItemWithText(String, Boolean, Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxdakxef(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this

`var index = listView1.FindItemWithText(textBox1.Text.ToLower());
MessageBox.Show(listView1.Items.IndexOf(index).ToString())`

to this

`var index = item.Index;
MessageBox.Show(listView1.Items[index].ToString())`

@johnny-mopp is correct that the finditemwithtext will only return one item, therefore it makes the loop completely redundant if you only wanted the first item.

Comment: Got 2 errors with your code. The first one is on the var index = item.index line so I changed item.index to item.Index, that error went away. The second error is on line 2: The error message is:- Non-invocable member ' ListView.Items ' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: Sorry, wrote the code on my iPad.  It should be Items[index] not Items(Index) so I have updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will work?

```
  var index = listView1.Select(x=>x.IndexOf(textBox1.Text.ToLower(), StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ... however, I got an error:- cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable.